# RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop with Matplotlib and Flask

Tags: multithreading, matplotlib, tensorflow, flask

I'm using flask, matplotlib to save image and tensorflow to create a session. I'm getting the above error when I run the following code. Does the flask route run on a separate thread? How can I make fig.saveFig piece of code run on the Main thread. Thanks a lot

```
 @app.route('/open', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
 def sendOutput():
     global loss,a2,xP,yP,scale,sess,fig
     test_X,test_Y = own_model.getEvaluateData(scale)
     cost,ans = sess.run([loss,a2],feed_dict={xP:test_X,yP:test_Y})
     d = np.array(ans) - np.array(test_Y)
     val = hist(d,100)
     sess.close()
     fig.saveFig('abc.png') //Errror on this line
```

Answer (score 87):

I was on the same situation, Flask with Matplotlib combo.
What worked for me is to specify Agg as Matplotlib backend.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Your code here
```

You can refer to Matplotlib documentation (Matplotlib in a web application server) for the details.

Comment: Note you need to put this code *before* any other imports, which might be already importing matplotlib or setting the Tkinter backend.

Comment: This works like a charm, Btw what does `Agg` actually do?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. My code works now but I still get a Warning UserWarning: Starting a Matplotlib GUI outside of the main thread will likely fail. Do you know about anything I could do to not get this warning?

Answer (score 3):

apparently this is an issue with TKinter. You don't have your full error message posted (you really should do that), but I'm working on something very similar so I'm 99.9% sure your problem is the same as mine. I'm building an app with tensorflow, flask, blah blah. I get the same error, intermittently (sometimes it works). Here are some links to similar questions. I hope this helps! I think my solution will be moving away from matplotlib.

- [Threaded client with the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694408/runtimeerror-main-thread-is-not-in-main-loop)
- [Running TKinter in a seperate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556479/running-a-tkinter-form-in-a-separate-thread/10556698#10556698)
- [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44026498/intermittent-error-while-plotting-graph-using-matplotlib-runtimeerror-main-thr)

Answer (score 0):

Threading issues. I had the same issue when working with lime. Here is what fixed it for me.

I changed from:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

To:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
    run_simple('localhost', 5000, app)
```