# Matplotlib and :RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop:

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, tkinter, multiprocessing

I'm trying to run multiple repetitive tasks in parallel under python. I'm pretty new to multiprocessing but as all the tasks are independant, I used the simple following piece of code :

```
    import numpy as np
    import sys
    import os
    import glob
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import concurrent.futures as Cfut
    
    def analize(simul, N_thread):
        path = os.getcwd()

        print('Analizing topo ...')
        Data = output of some calculations
    
        print('Writing Data ...')
        np.save('Data', Data)
    
        print('Data saved')
        print('Printing figures')

        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(Data[0])
        plt.savefig('figure1.pdf')

        plt.clf()
        plt.plot(Data[0])
        plt.savefig('figure1.pdf')

        plt.close('all')
        print('figures saved')
        os.chdir(path

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_simul = sorted(glob.glob('Layer*'))
    executor = Cfut.ProcessPoolExecutor(5)
   #executor = Cfut.ThreadPoolExecutor(N_jobs)
    futures = [executor.submit(analize, item, 10) for item in list_simul]
    Cfut.wait(futures)
```

It ran very well during 3 months, and since since morning I get sometimes the following error :

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method Image.__del__ of <tkinter.PhotoImage object at 0x7fac6c187f98>>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3359, in __del__
        self.tk.call('image', 'delete', self.name)
    RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

What is odd is that some jobs are done without any problem, and it happens not all the time. With a bit of research, I found a lot of posts with this problem, all of them were related to GUI. I understood the problem, but I guess I should be able to find a workaround since I'm not showing any figure, just creating the object and saving it, and since all the tasks are independent.

Any hint ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

matplotlib uses `TkAgg` for default. Backends like `TkAgg`, `FltkAgg`, `GTK`, `GTKAgg`, `GTKCairo`, `Wx`, and `WxAgg` are all GUI based. And most GUI backends require being run from the main thread. Thus, if you are running on an environment without GUI, it will throw `RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop`.

Therefore, just switch to backends that do not use GUI: `Agg`, `Cairo`, `PS`, `PDF`, or `SVG`.

For example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.switch_backend('agg')
```

---

References: https://matplotlib.org/stable/faq/howto_faq.html#work-with-threads

Answer (score 24):

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49921721/runtimeerror-main-thread-is-not-in-main-loop-with-matplotlib-and-flask), have you tried adding the following code to the top of your imports?

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```